# tryton: problem in taxes table when i add a negative value in the field quantity

Tags: tryton

Am using tryton 6.0.0,

In the table **Lines** ,I have create an invoice has two lines (the name of the account tax in both of them is "Umsatzsteuer – Normalsatz", one of them has a quantity positive and the other one has a negative value.

the story that after add a negative value  in quantity field to one line, like in the screenshoot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNLIw.png)

in the **Tax Lines** , there was 2 lines of taxes appear like in the screenshoot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg4lo.png)

i want to know, why the second line appear in **Tax Lines** table in case i add a negative value of quantity in the Lines table???

PS: the second line from the table **Tax Lines**  does not appear when i add a positive value of the quantity.

How i can fix that and why this thing happen if we add a negative value of quantity.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour because tryton allows to set different account on taxes depending on the sign. As the tax lines are used to properly create the account moves the amounts are splited based on the sign.